Where are the intermediate CA certificates?
In the folder /etc/ssl/certs/ i can well see:

Symbolic links to the certificates stored at /usr/share/ca-certificates/
The BUNDLE file ca-certificates.crt which contains all certificates in PEM format

I see only root CA certificates...i don't see the intermediate CA certificates ? Why ?
For example, with Let's encrypt CA, i can well find:

ISRG_Root_X1.pem
ISRG_Root_X2.pem

But where are the Let's encrypt intermediate certificates ? At the day i write this question, there are 4 intermediate CR certificates:

E5
E6
R10
R11

I guess there are somewhere on my computer, because i can successfully establish an SSL connection to a server (using let's encrypt certificate).

You misunderstand how certificates are used.
The ones you see are the trust-anchors.  These are the root CAs which you (or your OS, or your OS's developers) trust.
When you use connect to a remote service (e.g. a web-server), the server sends it's certificate (e.g. for unix.stackexchange.com) as well as any and all intermediate certificates required to verify that certificate all the way to a root.  The details are in RFC 5246.  You only trust that certificate chain if the root which signed the first intermediate is in your trust-anchor store, which is stored at /etc/ssl/certs/ as you noted.
So, to answer your question "But where are the Let's encrypt intermediate certificates ?" - they're installed on the remote system.
If you are the server, then your intermediate is stored in a file whose location depends on the service.  Generally, the service configuration file will have an entry which points to the intermediate certificate to be used, or (more likely) point to a chain file consisting of both the intermediate and server certificate.
If you've come from the Windows world, you may have seen intermediate CAs installed in the user or computer certificate store.  This is simply because Windows caches the intermediate CA certificates locally and makes them visible in the UI.

What was misleading me is that some applications (Mozilla Firefox) and OS (windows) stores the intermediate CA certificates...But it's not mandatory: the server must provide them. Many thanks again!

To add to this, if you use something like certbot to generate a Let's Encrypt cert, it will create three files - one containing the private key, one the signed certificate, and one the signed certificate along with intermediate certs. You're typically supposed to use the first and the last.

@floupinette It's not strictly mandatory that the server provide them either (although it certainly should). If the server omits intermediates, some clients will try to build a trust chain themselves, using cached intermediates and/or fetching them based on the Authority Information Access extension in the child certs. But this happens only at the client's whim, so servers shouldn't rely on it.

@GordonDavisson - very true.  One of the clients which won't is Firefox.  The standard does state that end-entities provide any intermediates to the relying parties.  AIA was added (at the request of Microsoft I believe) to allow for badly configured servers.

Don't expect to find them locally!
Most of the time, the process is the following :
During ssl negotiation, the server sends a PEM file with :

The server certificate
The CA intermediate server certificate

Locally, you just have the root CA certificate. It's enough to guarantee the trust of the whole chain.
NB: I talked about linux only. Mozilla Firefox works differently and store the intermediate CA certificates in an internal SQLite db.
This link opened my eyes:
Aarch_forum

Windows also seems to store some intermediate certs.  I've had sites with incomplete Digicert cert chains work in windows but not Linux because Windows had the issuer certs already.
